# Portugal visa, business or tourism?

Tags: visas, portugal

I am going to Portugal to attend one training program [as a participant] for 2 weeks.
This program is related to psychology. Which visa do I need to take, Business or tourism?

Answer (score 2):

If you:

- Are attending this course as part of your work
- Are a student and attending as part of your studies
- The course is organised by your company

you need a business visa.

> In regards to conference/seminar/workshop the following applicants can also apply for a Business visa:
>
> 1. Applicants-employees going to attend a  conference/seminar/workshop organised by their  company or another company directly related to
>    their company
> 2. Applicants-employees going to be actively  involved in a conference/seminar/workshop
> 3. Students going to attend a conference/s

- http://www.vfsglobal.com/Portugal/UK/Business.html